# Android: To convert HTML Content into the String

Tags: android, html, xml

I am getting HTML content into the my web service xml response. The following is my XML which I am getting as the response:

```
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Content>General Message Dr : Narendra Patel&lt;br/&gt;dsfsdf</Content>
</Table>
<Table>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Content>General Message Dr : Narendra Patel&lt;br/&gt;dsfsdf</Content>
</Table>
```

Now, in this XML I am getting the HTML Content into the Content tag.

I had try to convert that HTML Content into the plain text as follows:

```
String result= Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, "Content")).toString();
Log.i("Result is: ",result);
```

But the Result is:- 
General Message Dr : Narendra Patel

Actually the Result must be:- 
General Message Dr : Narendra Patel 
dsfsdf

Please help me. Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know.

```
String result= Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, "Content")).toString();
String without_html = Html.fromHtml(result).toString();
Log.d("asdas",without_html);
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP why he should follow your suggestion.